# Why shouldn't I directly access Instance properties for write operations?

Tags: javascript, object, instance, setter

So I read this [blog entry](http://bjorn.tipling.com/advanced-objects-in-javascript) recently. The author says:

> Although directly accessing and setting properties on instances still sets off my internal bad-javascript buzzer. Over time I have been trained by bugs and technical debt to avoid arbitrarily setting values on instances as a means to pass information around.

I heard that advice before, yet I still don't know what is bad about it in particular.

I see the possibility of validating values before actually setting them, but how should I handle a bad one? And is this the only reason to use a setter instead?

Comment: It's not something I've experienced.  Maybe it's just the way he codes that causes bugs and technical debt ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important reason (for me) to always use getters and setters instead of directly asccessing properties ist that you can always change the way they behave at a later point in time.

So if you publish a product or a library that has a `Cat` class with a `setName` method you are always able to decide that setting the name should do anything in addition in the future. For example writing to a log file "The name has been set" or something else with more effect.

If you don't use setters, you're stuck, because all the users of your library used the property `name` directly so you are doomed to keep that property forever and keep its name and never change anything about it our you will break everything your users built with it in the past.

So it's most important for public APIs used by others. If you stay internal you will still have a centralized point in the code to change behaviour.

See the difference:

```
 myCat.name = "Silvester"
```

if you have this in your code 5 times and you want to add the String "Cat:" to it you will have to find all the occurences and add "Cat:" to it.

If you use:

```
 myCat.setName("Silvester");
```

there's only one place to change, you can easily find it, and your users won't even notice you changed something.

Answer (score 1):

Using Setter and Getter ist broaldy common in other languages. In Java we have a convention, the  Java Bean Convention that describes the usages of Setters and Getters.

There are two design- principles that lead to using Setter and Getter: Its "Seperation Of Concern" and "Information Hiding".

The first one says, that a task or a feature should be implemented in one single object / module and that it should not be distributed over several places in your code and that an object should not implement several different features.

The second one says, that an object should hide every logic and implementation details that are not needed to use the feature / logic that the object provides.

If you apply these principle on an object that contains data, or even works with data you need to hide the way how the data is stored inside. And that is done by Setters and Getters.

For example. the user of an object does not need to know if the data is just a property, or if it is hold by a Map or an Array. Or imaginge a BUtton-Object that paints a button. The setColor()- function could just set a color-property in Button, or it could delegate to the underlying UI-framework.

Additionally I see a special case for JavaSCript. Since we don't really have priveate-attributes it is hard to hide attributes in an object that are not intendet to be changed by the objects user, because they hold some internal states. So the caller of an objects needs to know which properties may be changed and which not... this doesn't make the code easy readable... Using Setter and Getter makes that clear.